# Copy row [max] times while copying values of less frequent items [max-Y] times

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, copy

I have a dataframe comprised of 136 columns, 47 of which contain count data for specific factors. I am conducting association-rules analyses using the `arules` package which doesn't seem to interpret cumulative data  as the integers are regarded as unique items rather than cumulative counts (i.e. '3' is simply an object, rather than 3 instances of something). I am therefore trying to duplicate rows according to the maximum value in each row, while also duplicating any other numbers the appropriate amount of times. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(A1 = c(0,2,0,3),A2 = c(1,0,2,0), A3 = c(0,1,3,2))
```

Would become:

```
df <- data.frame(A1 = c(0,2,2,0,0,0,3,3,3), 
                 A2 = c(1,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0), 
                 A3 = c(0,1,0,3,3,3,2,2,0))
```

As you can see, a row with a maximum value of 3 would be duplicated 3 times. An associated 2 would be duplicated 2 times and the remaining cell would be filled with a 0.

Many of my cells contain large numbers an I'm going to have to do this again in the near future so if anyone has any advice, I'd be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data and answer

```
df <- data.frame(A1 = c(0,2,0,3),A2 = c(1,0,2,0), A3 = c(0,1,3,2))

ans <- data.frame(A1 = c(0,2,2,0,0,0,3,3,3), 
                 A2 = c(1,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0), 
                 A3 = c(0,1,0,3,3,3,2,2,0))
```

Solution

```
myfun <- function(row) {
   M <- max(row)
    apply(row, 2, function(x) c(rep(x, times=x), rep(0, times=M-x)))
}
library(magrittr)
test <-
    do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(x) myfun(df[x, ]))) %>%
        as.data.frame

all.equal(test, ans)
# TRUE
```

Comment: It's likely going to be slow so you may want to un-accept my answer and gather a few more solutions

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. It actually worked really well for me over a dataframe of several hundred rows and 47 columns.